# Referencing route param in AngularJS $routeProvider resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm attempting to use a route param in the resolve method of a $routeProvider route.  Here is my code:

```
.when('/agency/edit/:agencyId',
{
    controller: 'agencyController',
    templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Content/templates/agencyUpsert.html',
    resolve: {
        agency: ['$routeParams', 'agencyService', function ($routeParams, agencyService) {
            return agencyService.getAgency($routeParams.agencyId);
        }]
    }
})
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access it via `$routeParams.agencyId`, but I also tried `agencyId` directly (hoping it would be available in the content of the route), but it's undefined.

How can I reference it successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reference it using `$route` instead of `$routeParams` like this:

```
.when('/agency/edit/:agencyId',
{
    controller: 'agencyController',
    templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Content/templates/agencyUpsert.html',
    resolve: {
        agency: ['$route', 'agencyService', function ($route, agencyService) {
            return agencyService.getAgency($route.current.params.agencyId);
        }]
    }
})
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams):

> Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.

Comment: You're just collecting points from me this morning!  Thanks again.  I have to find better articles...